# Is there a way to refer to nested variable in Terraform script?

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I have a terraform script, which tries to refer to the attribute in the same resource. I need to pass "azurerm_container_group.aci_caddy.fqdn" to the container instance inside the container group.

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "aci_caddy" {
  resource_group_name = "aci_caddy"
  location            = local.location
  name                = "aci_caddy"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  dns_name_label      = "aci-caddykang"

  container {
    name   = "app"
    image  = "apptest:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "0.5"
    
    environment_variables = {
      SITE_ADDRESS = "${azurerm_container_group.aci_caddy.fqdn}"
    }

  }
}
```

but, I got the error message.

```
│ Error: Self-referential block
│ 
│   on aci-caddy-main.tf line 29, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "aci_caddy":
│   29:       SITE_ADDRESS = "${azurerm_container_group.aci_caddy.fqdn}"
│ 
│ Configuration for azurerm_container_group.aci_caddy may not refer to itself.
```

Is there a way to accomplish it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to export SITE_ADDRESS using your dns_name_label. So, instead of hardcoding dns_name_label. You can create a variable in Terraform

```
variable "dns_label" {
type = string
}
```

And then refer to this variable in your container group resource.

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "aci_caddy" {
  resource_group_name = "aci_caddy"
  location            = local.location
  name                = "aci_caddy"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  dns_name_label      = var.dns_label

  container {
    name   = "app"
    image  = "apptest:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "0.5"
    
    environment_variables = {
      SITE_ADDRESS = "${var.dns_label}-westus.azurecontainer.io"
    }

  }
}
```

If you want to further improve this, you can figure out how you can get the region/location from a azurerm provider data source. I am not exposed to azure provider, so couldn't find this quickly. But I know for a fact that FQDN is derived using your dns_name_label and .azurecontainer.io.

Comment: What a pit! We can not reference FQDN directly.  Follow your idea, with dns_label , region/location and "azurecontainer.io", we can generate the FQDN url.  the region/location can be retrieved by Data Resources. The only thing is we have to hardcode the string "azurecontainer.io".

Comment: If you end up using my suggestion, can you mark the answer useful ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant reference resource within itself: `azurerm_container_group.aci_caddy.fqdn` because it hasn't yet been created. You have to create new variable or local value for your SITE_ADDRESS.